# Subset confusion, how is it possivle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic

In question [IV] how is it wrong,i mean the subset will still remain even after subtraction of A-B so it has to be true?

In question [V] is it false because they are elements not subset?

Here in question [VII] its true? how while in question IV the answer was false? am i missing something here?

[image]

[sub](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60OFM.png)

Comment: for 4, it is true, but you wrote false on your test

Comment: You are missing a lot of information for this question.  What is question IV, for example. -1

Comment: it states that if phi exist in A-B right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the answers to all your questions written just right of the T/F

Question 4)

- Because $A=\{\ldots,\{\phi\},\ldots\}$, we have $ \{\phi\} \in A$ so that $ \{\{\phi\}\} \subset A$
- But in $A$ we do not have directly $\phi$, $A\neq\{\ldots,\phi,\ldots\}$. So that we have $ \phi \notin A$ and $\{\phi\} \not\subset A$

Question 5, 
$ \{\phi\} \in A$ but $ \phi \notin A$ so that $ \{3,\phi\} \not\subset A$

Question 7 is ok because 3 and 5 are element of $A$

Comment: is question 4 true or false?

Comment: The answer to question 4 is $F$. as I state $\{\phi\}\not\subset A$

Answer (score 0):

For any element $x$ and set $X$ we have $x \in X \iff \{x\} \subset X$

Note that

$\phi \notin A-B$ but $\{\phi\} \in A-B$

and so

$\{\phi\} \not \subset A-B$ but $\{\{\phi\}\} \subset A-B$